# I want to do a factory reset with recovery system. Recovery "enter" button is the home button. My device doesn't have a home button

Tags: recovery-mode, factory-reset

Good day.
I want to enter the recovery and do a factory reset, because I've been locked out.

As stated, my device doesn't have a home button , but the "enter" button in recovery mode is the home button, not the power button. There's a reset pinhole, tried it , but I'm still at the lock screen that requires my email and password. My device can't be connected to Wi-Fi anymore. The Volume Up & Down scrolls through the options.

Device is NOT rooted

Device Model: DINAMIK M2in1  (Don't bother trying to find it, it's extinct even on the net)

Android version Unknown

Android System Recovery 3e

Comment: `I'm still at the lock screen that requires my email and password` that sounds more like the factory reset protection (FRP) which is not removed by a factory reset.

Comment: @Robert I looked up FRP and what it looks like, and I can say It's not that. It's the normal too many pattern attempts email screen.